# Content Security Policy (CSP) setting blocking download of SCV file

Tags: csv, content-security-policy

The users of my app need to be able to download a template CSV file:

`<a target="_blank" download="template.csv" href="./template.csv">Download Template</a>`

This works fine in my standalone app (no CSP headers configured) but when I integrate it into another application with some custom CSP headers defined - the downloaded file contains the html of the webpage and not the actual content of the csv file. So far I haven't been able to find which CSP header value needs adjusting. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: When CSP blocks something, a corresponding message should appear in the browser console. Please add this message to the question.

Comment: @granty: the file download is not blocked - the csv file gets downloaded but it's content is the html of the containing page - that is why I'm so buffled.

Comment: It's not a CSP related issue. Look at the contents of this HTML file, it may be page 404(file not found) or 403(access denied).